# Something removes apps from startup

Tags: windows-7, boot

I don't know why, but something removes apps from startup.

For example, I want slack to run on startup.

I add it to startup folder or even through regedit.

I reboot my pc and slack is running.

I reboot my pc another time and it is not running any more.

So after PC loads first time it launch slack but after that something removes it from startup. I've installed Autoruns for Windows (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and I see that after first reboot Slack dissapear from startup at all.

I've checked PC for viruses using dr.Web cureIt and Avast with no result.

Comment: Some applications in their preferences allow you to specify whether they should run on start-up. If this is not set and you run it by other means it may well change the start-up folder or registry to reflect its internal setting.

Comment: I've tried it too, I've event reinstalled some apps. But anyway - they launch on first reboot and didn't launch after that.

Comment: There is a `RunOnce` registry folder which does exactly that, intended for post-installation configuration when a reboot is required: I assume you are not using that. I think you are going to need to use something like SysInternals' [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) to catch file changes to the start-up folder you used (either current user or all users) or registry changes to whichever `Run` folder you used.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try is using Group Policy or Task Scheduler to run this on startup.

If you choose to use Task Scheduler, you can try these steps:

1. Open Task Scheduler. You can search for it in the start menu.
2. Create a New Task.
3. Ensure that your trigger is either upon login or on startup. If it is on startup you will need to assign the proper permissions to to the task.
4. Define the action that will happen, in your case running slack.

Save the task and then restart your machine. If you login and slack doesn't start, open Task Scheduler and search for the task you created. In the 'last run' column, the status of the outcome will be reported. If slack was terminated or something failed to execute, you will know...

Hope this is of some use,

Comment: Thanks. That works, but I want to find reason and launch on startup(not by task).

Comment: If it worked then you didn't get an error, right?

Comment: With Task Scheduler, everything is launching.

Comment: Does this fix your problem then? It appears it is launching on startup

Comment: It's a kind of hack. because if I just install new app - I will need to manually add task for it. So problem is not solved.

Comment: Does your PC have Group Policy editor?